# run menu item of another app in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menu

I need to get the menu of the screen currently in foreground and then get its menu items and run one of its menu item. Can we do this programmatically? 
I can get the ApplicationDescriptor with its module name with the code below:

```java
int moduleHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("module name");
ApplicationDescriptor[] apDesArr = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(moduleHandle); 

ApplicationDecriptor  apDes = apDesArr[0];
```

But what should I do next. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I get the screen through this code:

```java
private static void runMenuItem(String menuItemText) {

  Screen screen = Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen();

  Menu menu = screen.getMenu(0);

  for (int i = 0, cnt = menu.getSize(); i < cnt; i++)

    if(menu.getItem(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(menuItemText))

            menu.getItem(i).run();
}
```

But the first line of this code pops up an exception: No Application Instance. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach won't work. You can't access other screens outside your application context.

You can still try using [event injection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Event-injection/ta-p/444735). A well-tuned key-injection hack could do the job (you could inject a menu key press to open it, inject scroll down to the desired position and finally inject a trackwheel click to select the option). The problem is that this approach is not reliable enough. For instance, many apps use event injection to programmatically close the camera app, but on OS 6.0 there are some models where this doesn't work. If a new version of the target app is released and the  menu item position changes, won't work. And you sometimes need to call `Thread.sleep` between each injected event to make it work, but this is very device-dependent.

In short, you could have an experimental hack working on some models or OS versions, but it is not something to let in production code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mister. It was very helpful. Just one thing more I need to know that, can we guarantee the order of key presses when we inject multiple key presses and trackwheel events? If yes, then how? Thnanks in advance.

Comment: It should follow the sequence of calls made by you in the code, but take into account that user generated events can happen at anytime, so the user can mess with your events. Also in my experience there's no guarantee for an event to do anything, in particular where 2 or more are injected very quickly (In those cases calling `Thread.sleep` between events usually help).

Comment: Yes I also have noticed this that Thread.sleep helps when injecting two or more events. Thanks so much for your response.